# make dynamic switch to different database based on logged in user's credentials?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Database.php**

```
<?php
class Database extends CI_Controller {
    public $branch_db;

    function __construct($company_name, $branch_name) {
        parent::__construct();
        $branch_db = $this->load->database($company_name.'_db_'.$branch_name);
    }
}
?>
```

**Account_model.php**

```
protected function verifyLogin($username, $password) {
    $this->db->trans_start();

    $sql = "SELECT password, company_id, branch_id
                FROM account
                WHERE username = {$username}"; //Prepare statement

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result_num = $query->num_rows();

    if ($result_num == 1) {
        $first_row = $query->row();
        $stored_password = $first_row->password;

        if (password_verify($password, $stored_password)) {
            //Successful login
            //Get company name
            //Get branch name
            //Set database
            //Pass company_name, branch_name
            //All models must be able to access the dynamically loaded database
        }
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

There are multiple databases that can be accessed. For each branch there is a dynamically created database. Each branch has an account. When an account is logged in, the database related to that account will be accessed. That database will then be used for the entire session until the user logs out.

I have a main database where a master list of the valid username/password combinations are stored. I had that declared in my `database.php` in the `config` folder. But after the user logs in, I will need to switch to the database related to that user account so they can access their data.

How can I use this controller for my models so they all access that same database (without having to redo `$this->load->database()` over and over)?

Comment: Means? You want to load database on every function of model?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much I guess? Like, I sort of want to make that db equivalent to `$this->db`, have it globally accessible to all models (each database has the same table structure anyway) @JayminsFakeAccount

Answer (score 0):

In Your database.php `Application->config->database.php`
 I am expecting that you create a session and store admin_type variable as it logged in.

```
$admin_type = $this->session->userdata['admin_type'];
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
 if ($admin_type==1) {
   $db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'name_db',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
}else{
    $db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'name_db2',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
}
```

Comment: There are multiple databases that can be accessed. After log in, based on the user's branch and company, that particular database will be accessed instead. How can I do that? Without having to do `$this->load->database()` over and over in my models?

Comment: I guess after login there will be change in links too right? you can do that putting if coditions too let me edit the code for the same.

Comment: I have edited the code you can see and can fit into your requirements

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to pass a variable to the database.php in the config folder?

Comment: I have updated my question. basically for every branch, a new database is created. Each branch has an account. When an account is logged in, the database related to that account will be accessed. That database will then be used for the entire session until the user logs out. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it can be possible  and after he loggs out after that branch you can destroy the sessions and cookies

Comment: The name of the database isn't static though. <company name>_db_<branch name> is the format. So I will just set a session variable for that?